# how to do the count for if student count is greate then some number?

Tags: sql

I have a table called teacher_student_course with teacher_id, student_id, and course_id how would I return a course_id for a course where the student count is lets say above 50?

please help my mind is shot its midnight!

Comment: Look into `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by the course_id and get all group having more than 50 records like this.

```
SELECT course_id
FROM teacher_student_course
GROUP BY course_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
```

If you want to check if a course has more than 50 students or not, you need to use a similar query but with a JOIN as shown below.

```
SELECT tsc.course_id
FROM teacher_student_course tsc 
         INNER JOIN course ON course.id = tsc.course_id
WHERE course = 'course name'
GROUP BY tsc.course_id
HAVING COUNT(tsc.course_id)>50;
```

[Demo for count greater than 4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3695b/8)

Comment: @user1884193 which query worked for you?

Comment: The first one was what I was looking for. Thank you.